# Questions about unused argument errors

Tags: r

I am very new to R and am trying to run this code:

```r
kabcFull.cov <- cor2cov(kabcFull.cov,sds = c(3.40,2.40,2.90,2.70,2.70,4.20,2.80,3.00))
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Error in cor2cov(kabcFull.cov, sds = c(3.4, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.7, 4.2, 2.8,  :
> unused argument (sds = c(3.4, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.7, 4.2, 2.8, 3))

I am wondering what could be incorrect. I searched the previous information on Stack regarding the "unused argument error", but I am not quite finding a match for what could be the issue. Thank you again in advance for your time.

Comment: Where does the `cor2cov` function come from? That's not a base R function. What does it's documentation say about what arguments it expects?

Comment: I bet this error stems from the fact that the argument is named `sd` and not `sds`.

Comment: It looks like sds is an acceptable code (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/childsds/versions/0.7.6/topics/sds), but I don't know what could be the issue otherwise.

Comment: `sds()` is a totally different function that you linked to. `sd = ` is an argument that you can use in `cor2cov()`. `sds = ` isn't an argument for `cor2cov()`.